# "Message" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject error

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I received a "Message" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject error after trying to click on a button in my app. The app compiles just fine and I can use every other part of my app. The interesting thing is that it runs just fine in iOS7 but crashes in iOS6. I have read to prefix my entity but since it is called in about 50 classes I am checking to see if there is a different solution. I am also curious why it works in iOS7 but not iOS6. Also If I delete the MessageUI.framework it works on iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: You should *always* prefix your classes (particularly when it is named something as common as "Message"). You can easily rename your classes by right-clicking on the class name and selecting "Refactor > Rename". Xcode will do the rest (well... if it does not crash ;)).

Comment: It didn't seem to let me do the refractor>rename. After I change the name of the entity from "Message" to XMessage" I receive some different errors which people said I will have to delete and recreate my database in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I use the default on the CONFIGURATIONS/Default (Class is the same as the Entity name: my image example of "WebResource" that I would get an exception

```
 reason: '"WebResource" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
```

at statement:

WebResource *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WebResource" inManagedObjectContext:mymanagedObjectContext];

but all works fine if i change the Class to "NSManagedObject".  I do not know why the default is not "NSManagedObject" :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems some names just don't work for entities: `Message`, `WebResource`, `BluetoothDevice` (as of iOS 11).

Renaming the entity and associated class solved it for me.